# Fire code after field is validated with Parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

ParsleyJS's documentation says that you can use the following code to fire more code once a field is validated successfully.

```
$("#fieldid").parsley().on('field:success', function() {
    alert("It's validated!");
});
```

I've tried `data-parsley-ui-enabled="true"` and `data-parsley-trigger="input"` on the `form` tag.

Am I missing something else? Thanks!

Comment: Should work....

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune It works when I submit the form but I was looking to add classes after the value changes and is validated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like as below:

```
$("#fieldid").parsley().on('field:success', function() {
    alert("Name validated!");
}).on('field:validated', function() {
        //If Name is validated, then only fire more code
        if($("#name").parsley().isValid())
    {
        alert("Fire more code for Name!");
      }
});
```

Here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/9t1L4jwp/)**